# What are all invariant random subgroup on Sub ($R^n$) and Sub($G$)?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, algebraic-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. The space Sub($G$) be the closed subgroup of $G$ and $\mu$ be a borel probability measure of Sub($G$) which is invariant under all inner automorphism.

What are all such measure other than point mass measure? Is there any classification for $R^n$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? For instance, do you know any examples of $G$'s for which all IRS's of $G$ are supported on closed normal subgroups?  I suggest, you ask a more focused question.

Comment: I suggest to read an introduction to the subject, since it usually provides a number of examples (one should not expect a definite answer). As Moishe suggests, a more focused question would better fit here.

Comment: Is there any classification for R^n?